# Can't find error in code about retrieve contents from HTML file

Tags: jquery

I would preciate if someone could help me to get the code below to work. The goal is to read the content of a web page and display it in a div that is called #content. What could be wrong?

```
function content(){
 $.ajax({
  url : “page.html”,
  success : function (data) {
   $(“#content”).html(data);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: are there any javascript errors?  can you maybe post your html too.

Comment: I posted the HTML code at first, but it was removed

Answer (score 2):

Your quotation marks certainly look quite odd.

Change them to normal `"`:

```
function content(){
 $.ajax({
  url : "page.html",
  success : function (data) {
   $("#content").html(data);
  }
 });
}
```

You could just use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) as well though...

```
$('#content').load("page.html");
```

Comment: It's not working, must both file be on a server? I was running this local on my computer?

Comment: Yes, for ajax to work, both files must be on a server and in the same document.domain

Comment: But if I want to retrieve info from other web pages that's not on the same server, is that impossible due to security or is there another way? I want to retrieve contents of some divs and show the contents in another div on a new web page??

Comment: @user790843 You can always use `iframe`s to display content from other servers, but you cannot embed content from other pages into your own DOM without using a proxy.

Comment: OK, using a proxy? That's new for me, how does that work in brief?

Comment: You can either have a server-side script that downloads the contents of a page onto your server, after which the ajax can load the data from that script (as its under same origin). Alternatively, you can use a JSONP proxy which serves JSON content wrapped around a function, which makes it accessible even across domains.

Answer (score 0):

The page that includes the script must be loaded from a web server otherwise you will be seeing `XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxx.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` style errors. [Cross-site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) requests like this are not allowed (be default) due to security concerns, although they [are possible](http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-site-xmlhttprequest/).

If you serve your test page from a web server, the request will be allowed. Most modern browsers include a JavaScript or Error console that detail errors of this kind.